# Mysql Restore from binlogs

Tags: mysql, restore

How can we make one database restore date to date, like "sunday to wednesday" but from one binlog file?

Thanks,
Pedro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`mysqlbinlog`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html).  To specify start and end dates, use the `--start-datetime` and `--stop-datetime` arguments; they are documented on the `mysqlbinlog` page in the MySQL Manual.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first restore your last full backup which was before the point you want to restore to. Then replay the binlogs from that point (The backup should probably have been created containing the binlog position - if not you'll have to try to work it out) up to the point you want to restore to.